# how to increase counter for every 10nth element

Tags: javascript

I need to write a logic that increases the counter after every 10th element. i.e 10th, 20th and so on. if there are more than 10 elements counter would increase to 1 and if it is greater than 20, the counter value would become 2

```
const ele = 10; // possible values 10, 20, 30
let counter = 0;

if(ele.lemgth > 10){
  counter++
}
console.log(counter) // logs 1
enter code here
```

Any advice, please.

Comment: it sounds like you need to loop?

Comment: You could do `counter += Math.floor(ele/10)`?

Also you do not need to call `.length` on a number. If it is actually a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just devide the number of elements by 10.
If you want to accomodate for values in between the 10, 20, 30 you propose, you can do math.floor() to round down.

```js
const ele = 10; // possible values 10, 20, 30
let counter = Math.floor(ele/10);
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: ah man, sometimes I feel so dumb for not being able to think of an obvious solution. Many thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need this:

```
const count = 35;
const every = 10;
let counter = 0;

for(let i=0; i<=count; i+=every) {
 counter++
}
```

Comment: Your logic sets counter to 1 when the number of elements is below 10. 
0-10 should output 0
11-20 should output 1
etc

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = [1,2,3,4,5, ... etc];
const ele = 10;
let counter = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if ((i + 1) % 10 === 0 ) {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that way, yoy always have the counter right. If ele=120, counter=12, if ele=10, counter=1.

```js
    var ele = 120;
    let counter = 0;

    counter = Math.floor(ele / 10);
    console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [] // any array could go here
let counter = 0;

//check to see if the length of the array is evenly divisible by 10
if(array.length % 10 === 0){

  //if the array is divisible by 10, you don't need to loop through it
  //divide the length of the array by 10
  counter = array.length/10;

}else{

   //if the array is not evenly divisible by 10,
   //run a loop in iterations of 10 to get the correct counter
   for(let i=0; i<=array.length; i+=10) {
      counter++;
   }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the logic. Hope this helps.